# How to start the map phase while the reduce phase is working

Tags: java, hadoop, reduce, mapper

I have this scenario. JobA and JobB. Is there a chance to start the JobB mapping phase using the data provided by the JobA reduce phase while this is still working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes in my mind is to have a thread(started in your driver class) which permanently checks the output directory of JobA.
When a particular(set of) part-r-xxxx file(s) were created and completely written you can start JobB having as input that particular(set of) part-r-xxxx file(s).

The only problem I can identify now is the one related to checking whether a part-r-xxxx file was completely written.

Comment: You wont see a part-r- file until it has been completely written by a particular reducer. So you could start processing part-r files as they appear and you will know they are complete.